# Object based functions in JS?

Tags: javascript, function, oop

So, I have seen many JS functions that need two parameters, one of which is specified while calling the function i.e. `function(param)` and the other is specified using objects i.e. `var.function(param)` with the function needing `var` and `param`. So I want to know how I can get `var`

Comment: Please provide a more robust example that demonstrates the issue more explicitly. See [mcve]. `var.function()` isn't even valid syntax

Comment: @charlietfl it is 
e.g. string.search(tosearch)

Comment: "Object based functions" are called **methods**. If you are invoking a method on an object, you can access the object [using the `this` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/1048572) inside the function.